# Adding MinGW Path for posix version

Tags: cmake, path, mingw32

This is my cmake mingw32 toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

######################################################
# Compiler Flags
######################################################
set(COMMON_FLAGS "") 
set(COMMON_FLAGS ${COMMON_FLAGS} -static)
set(COMMON_FLAGS ${COMMON_FLAGS} -static-libgcc)
set(COMMON_FLAGS ${COMMON_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++) 

set(COMMON_FLAGS_DEBUG "")
set(COMMON_FLAGS_RELEASE "")
set(C_FLAGS "")
set(CXX_FLAGS "")

set(C_FLAGS_DEBUG     ${COMMON_FLAGS} ${WARNING_FLAGS} ${COMMON_FLAGS_DEBUG}   ${C_FLAGS}) 
set(C_FLAGS_RELEASE   ${COMMON_FLAGS} ${WARNING_FLAGS} ${COMMON_FLAGS_RELEASE} ${C_FLAGS}) 
set(CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   ${COMMON_FLAGS} ${WARNING_FLAGS} ${COMMON_FLAGS_DEBUG}   ${CXX_FLAGS})
set(CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${COMMON_FLAGS} ${WARNING_FLAGS} ${COMMON_FLAGS_RELEASE} ${CXX_FLAGS})

######################################################
# Linker flags
######################################################
string(REPLACE ";" " " LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${COMMON_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
string(REPLACE ";" " " LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "${COMMON_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
string(REPLACE ";" " " LINKER_FLAGS "${COMMON_FLAGS}")
```

I can create with this toolchain file my makefiles.

And when I use the

> i686-6.4.0-release-**win32**-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0

I don't need to add the compiler folder to the PATH to compile and link the project.

But when I use the

> i686-6.4.0-release-**posix**-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0

I have to add the compiler to the PATH for compilation. If I don't add the posix version to the path I got an error message during compilation

> The code execution cannot proceed because libwinpthread-1.dll was not
>   found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

Is it possible to use the posix version without adding to path? What do I have to add in my toolchain file?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Aren't `libwinpthread-1.dll` is located near to your "posix" toolchain?

Comment: For *win32* and for *posix* it is located at "../bin", "opt/bin" and "../i686-w64-mingw32/lib"